# Safely pass input line by line (from generator) to subprocess' stdin on Python

Tags: subprocess, generator

I want to manage a subprocess with the subprocess module, and I need to pipe a (really) large numbers of lines to the child stdin. I'm creating the input with a generator, and passing onto the subprocess like this:

```py
def my_gen (end): # simplified example
  for i in range(0, end):
    yield f"line {i}"

with subprocess.Popen(["command", "-o", "option_value"], # simplified example
  stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = sys.stdout, stderr = sys.stderr) as process:
  for line in my_gen(1e7):
    process.stdin.write(line.encode()) # This is apparently not safe
  out, err = process.communicate() # out and err will be None, 
  # but this closes the process gracefully, which "with" does too
```

This results in a Broken Pipe Error, although it does't happen all the time on every machine I've tried:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_script", line 170, in <module>
    process.stdin.write(line.encode())
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/tolib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 171, in <module>
  File "path/tolib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 914, in __exit__
    self.stdin.close()
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

So, what's the safe way to pass input line by line from a generator to a subprocess?

Edit: I've been getting suggestions about using communicate, which is of course in the docs. That answers how to communicate safely, but it doesn't accept a generator as input.
Edit2: as Booboo pointed out, the example will throw a runtime error (not the one I was finding in my code), the call to range should be `range(0, int(end))` so `my_gen` can accept numbers in `1e7` notation.

Comment: But communicate doesn't take a generator as input, even if the generator yields encoded strings...

Comment: "Broken pipe" indicates that your subprocess probably shut down when you weren't expecting it to. Changing how you write lines isn't going to fix that. You need to figure out why your subprocess is ending.

Comment: `communicate` is designed to avoid common deadlock issues, but this isn't a deadlock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you want `stdout` and `stderr` to not be piped, then either do not specify these arguments to the `Popen` call at all or specify their values as `None`, the default value if not specified (but do not specify these as `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr`).

Why not? Looking at the source for the `Popen.communicate` method I can see that there is special optimized code for the case where there is only one non-None argument and when that argument is the *sysin* argument then `Popen.communicate` is implemented by simply doing a write of the past input string to the pipe **and ignores any `BrokenPipeError` error that might occur**. But by passing the *stdout* and *stderr* arguments as you are, I suspect that `communicate` is confused and is now starting threads to handle the processing and this is ultimately intermittently leading to your exception.

Now I believe that you can execute your writes without using `communicate` *and* also ignore the `BrokenPipeError`. When I tried the following code (substituting my own command being executed by `Popen` that writes what is being piped in to a file and using text mode), I, in fact, did not encounter any `BrokenPipeError` exceptions (nor do I expect to with the proper setting of *stdout* and *stderr*). So I can't swear to whether the output will still be correct if such an exception should occur.

As an aside, the `range` built-in function does not take a float object (at least not for me), so I don't know how you are able to specify `1e7`.

I have also modified the code to add terminating newline characters at the end of each line and to process in text mode, but you should not feel constrained to do so.

```py
import subprocess
import sys

def my_gen (end): # simplified example
    for i in range(0, end):
        yield f"line {i}\n"

with subprocess.Popen(["command", "-o", "option_value"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, text=True) as process: # simplified example
    for line in my_gen(10_000_000):
        try:
            process.stdin.write(line)
        except BrokenPipeError as e:
            pass
    out, err = process.communicate()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the comment on communicate's inner workings. It would have never occurred to me to look at the source code for such things. Also, you're right about the 1e7 thing (its was just a dummy example and forgot that that notation generates floats)

Answer (score 0):

Docs say to use `.communicate`:

> **Warning:** Use `communicate()` rather than `.stdin.write`, `.stdout.read` or `.stderr.read` to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but communicate takes encoded strings as input, (it doesn't work if the generator yields encoded strings, neither), and I can't use `"\n".join(...)` because the input is really long (hundred of millions of lines). Although I talked about generators in the text and about doing it line-by-line on the title, I've added the generator thing to the title, too

Comment: You can repeatedly call `communicate` to send each chunk/line, like you currently are doing with `.stdin.write`